# error importing igraph

Tags: python-2.7, installation, igraph, anaconda

On importing igraph in python, I get an error (see below). Since igraph is not part of anaconda, I executed the below outlined steps for installation.

What is libglpk.35.dylib, how should I load it, and why is this problem occurring?

### igraph cannot be imported

```
'' import igraph
'' Traceback (most recent call last):
''   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
''   File "/Users/claushaslauer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    '' from igraph._igraph import *
'' ImportError: dlopen(/Users/claushaslauer/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.10.dylib
''   Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libglpk.35.dylib
''   Reason: image not found
```

### installation steps

1. install homebrew via `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. install pkg-config (via [igraph-help](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2015-03/msg00013.html))  `brew install pkg-config`
3. install igraph via homebrew: `brew install igraph`
4. link: `brew install homebrew/science/igraph`
5. `pip install python-igraph`

### following suggestions from Evert:

1. `brew uninstall igraph`
2. `brew uninstall gmp`
3. `brew uninstall glkp` -- `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/glkp`
4. `brew install igraph`

   ==> Installing igraph from homebrew/homebrew-science
   ==> Installing igraph dependency: gmp
   ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/gmp-6.0.0a.yosemite.bottle.
   Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gmp-6.0.0a.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
   ==> Pouring gmp-6.0.0a.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
   Error: The brew link step did not complete successfully
   The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
   Could not symlink include/gmp.h
   Target /usr/local/include/gmp.h
   already exists. You may want to remove it:
     rm '/usr/local/include/gmp.h'

   To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
     brew link --overwrite gmp

   To list all files that would be deleted:
     brew link --overwrite --dry-run gmp

   Possible conflicting files are:
   /usr/local/include/gmp.h
   /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a
   ==> Summary
     /usr/local/Cellar/gmp/6.0.0a: 15 files, 3.2M
   ==> Installing igraph
   ==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-science/igraph-0.7.1.yosemi
   Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/igraph-0.7.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
   ==> Pouring igraph-0.7.1.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz
     /usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1: 83 files, 6.4M

   - what does "Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully" imply?
   - I don't see anything related to `/usr/local/lib/libglpk.35.dylib` -- when I call python now, the same error occurs as before.

### Solution with Evert's help

thanks Evert for the additional answer. With this content, I can import igraph now. Three things to note:

1. When I say `brew tap homebrew/sciene`, log in with my github credentials, I get

   ```
   remote: Repository not found.
   fatal: repository 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-sciene/' not found
   Error: Failure while executing: git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-sciene /usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-sciene --depth=1
   ```

   I am not sure how critical this is, as it turned out, I can run igraph without this. However, the URL `https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-sciene/` produces a 404 error for me.
2. `brew search glpk` and `brew search igraph` both return the one line output pointing to `homebrew/science/...`
3. `brew link --overwrite gmp` says it created 11 symlinks. I think this is what solved my issue so now I can import igraph fine in python.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are there any warnings or errors when you run `pip install python-igraph`? Or at `brew install igraph`?

Comment: `libglpk.35.dylib` is a dependency library for igraph; it should get automatically installed when you `brew install igraph` (it does for me). Ditto libgmp.10.dylib.

Comment: Try uninstalling igraph (`brew uninstall igraph`), as well as the dependencies (`gmp`, `glkp`), then reinstall and copy-paste the log into your question. My log shows that running `brew install igraph` installs `gmp-6.0.0a.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz` and `glpk-4.52.yosemite.bottle.1.tar.gz`, for example.

Comment: We'll solve the linking problem later, but could you try just `brew install glpk`: installing the missing dependency. I'd like to know what error homebrew gives there.

Comment: you misspelled science

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `glpk` dependency is missing, because when installing `igraph`, only the default packages are searched for. `glpk` lives, just like `igraph`, in an extra homebrew repository called [homebrew/science](https://github.com/homebrew/homebrew-science). You can automatically access that repository by "tapping" it:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
```

Now, all packages included in this repository are also searched for. To confirm, try and see if the following two commands give just the package name back:

```
brew search glpk

brew search igraph
```

---

Before reinstalling `igraph`, you have to fix the link issue with `gmp`; this is just a result of homebrew not completely uninstalling `igraph` and its dependencies during the uninstall step. For this, you can follow homebrew's suggestion:

```
brew link --overwrite gmp
```

(You're overwriting the `gmp` package with the previously and still partly installed `gmp` package; they are the same, so no harm is done.)

---

Now, you should be able to install igraph:

```
brew install igraph
```

If this also gives a warning/error about links, use the same `--overwrite` option as for `gmp`.

In case `brew install igraph` did not install `glpk` (i.e., you didn't see a message like "==> Installing igraph dependency: glpk"), you can simply install it separately:

```
brew install glpk
```

Give or take a minor detail, you should now have a working igraph installation (and, since you never uninstalled python-igraph, this should also still work).