# Install python-igraph in Mac OSX Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, anaconda, igraph

I have anaconda installed in my Mac. I am trying to install python-igraph.

I tried the following commands to install it:

```
$ brew install igraph
$ pip install python-igraph
```

My python setup:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin`
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
```

But when I try to import `igraph`, I get the following error:

```
>>> import igraph
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> File
>   "/Users/arefindk/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/**init**.py",
>   line 34, in
>
> ```
> from igraph._igraph import *
> ```
>
> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Users/arefindk/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: _iconv
>
> Referenced from:
>   /Users/arefindk/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so
>
> Expected in: flat namespace
>
> in
>   /Users/arefindk/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so

Now, I have tried to follow all the steps that is provided in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505490/error-importing-igraph).

My hunch is, it might be a problem related to Anaconda because my friend successfully installed and imported python-igraph using the above commands and he doesn't have Anaconda installed.

How can I both solve this problem and keep Anaconda in my Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've attempted 2 different ways, neither of them is supposed to work with Anaconda. First, on Mac `igraph` can not be installed simply by `pip` because it fails to compile the underlying `C` bindings. Second, the Python distribution installed and managed by `brew` is usually independent from the one of Anaconda. Actually you might have already `igraph` in your `brew` managed Python, but then you need to call that Python not the Anaconda one. Assuming you have other ties to Anaconda and you want to stick to that distribution, you need to look for packages in official or unofficial Anaconda repositories. In order to have `igraph` with plotting functionality, you need the followings:

- the `igraph` C library
- `python-igraph` for Python 2.7
- `cairo 1.12` (C library)
- `py2cairo`

Here I show you the versions that worked for me few months ago:

```
conda install -y -c vgauthier cairo=1.12.18
conda install -y -c pkgw py2cairo
# if you want it for Python 3:
# conda install -y -c richlewis pycairo=1.10.0
conda install -y -c bioconda python-igraph
```

If the above doesn't work for you, search for other package options in the Anaconda repositories, [like this one](https://anaconda.org/vgauthier/repo?type=conda&label=main).

Comment: `conda install -y -c bioconda python-igraph` worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Not working anymore ```conda install -y -c bioconda python-igraph
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python-igraph
```

Comment: what about `conda install -c conda-forge python-igraph`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `conda install -c conda-forge python-igraph` worked fine for me, after many other attempts to install in macOS mojave. 
Also worth remembering to search the anaconda site https://anaconda.org/search?q=igraph